# imwheel different config for trackpoint/trackpad/mouse

Tags: 18.04, trackpoint

I'm using a Thinkpad with Ubuntu 18.04.

Is it possible to have a different imwheel configuration for scroll speed between pointing devices? I want to configure my trackpad, trackpoint, and mouse scroll speeds differently.

Comment: Did you ever finger this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I’ve ended up using windows because of this and other issues.